# How to send Gmail emais with DKIM or SPF to my own account?

Tags: gmail

I am playing around with the [Gmail Flight Reservation markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/flight-reservation) and the [testing page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema) says it works if I send me and email form myself (`to` and `from` being my own account), but I still need SPF or DKIM to make it work.

How can I programmatically send an email, from my own account, to myself, in Gmail, using DKIM or SPF?